# I am trying to purge all data from a cloud storage Search & Conversation Data Store App in GCP, won't purge

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, jupyter-lab

I need to delete all data from the data store app so that it can then be deleted.  Everytime I try, it says it successfully deleted the blobs but they are still there.  I am using a python notebook in jupyterlab

Thoughts?

```
from google.cloud import storage

def purge_gcs_data(bucket_name, folder):
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
print(f"Storage bucket is '{bucket.name}'")

    # Delete individual record files
    record_blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f"{folder}/")
    for blob in record_blobs:
        print(f"Deleting {blob.name}...")
        blob.delete()

    # Delete the metadata file
    metadata_blob = bucket.blob(f"{folder}/metadata.jsonl")
    if metadata_blob.exists():
        print("Deleting metadata.jsonl...")
        metadata_blob.delete()

    # Check if the folder is now empty
    remaining_blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f"{folder}/"))
    if not remaining_blobs:
        print(f"Confirmation: All objects in '{folder}' of bucket '{bucket_name}' have been      successfully purged.")
    else:    
        for blob in remaining_blobs:
            print(blob.name)
    
            try:
                remaining_blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f"{folder}/"))
                if not remaining_blobs:
                    print(f"Confirmation: All objects in '{folder}' of bucket '{bucket_name}' have been successfully purged.")
                else:
                    print("Warning: Some objects were not deleted:")
                for blob in remaining_blobs:
                    print(f"Remaining Object: {blob.name}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error during fetching remaining blobs: {e}")

# Call the function 
PROJECT_ID_SUFFIX = PROJECT_ID.split("-")\[-1\]
GCS_BUCKET = f"shared-aif-bucket-{PROJECT_ID_SUFFIX}"
GCS_FOLDER = "clinical note summarization demo"

purge_gcs_data(GCS_BUCKET, GCS_FOLDER)
```

I have tried with and without if statements, I've tried a try/except.  It always looks successful till I go to the Data App

Answer (score 0):

Try using **get_bucket** instead of **bucket**:

```
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Take a look at this reference from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/2.0.0/buckets#deleteblobblobname-clientnone-generationnone-ifgenerationmatchnone-ifgenerationnotmatchnone-ifmetagenerationmatchnone-ifmetagenerationnotmatchnone-timeout60-retrygooglecloudstorageretryconditionalretrypolicy-object).